# flask failed to import module between classes

Tags: python-3.x, web-services, flask

I have a Flask app structured in this way:

```
¦   start_service.bat
¦   WebService.py
¦   WebServiceClass.py
¦   test_prediction_class.py
¦   __init__.py
¦
+---Common_utils
¦   ¦   CommonClass.py
¦   ¦   __init__.py
¦   ¦
¦   +---Tables
¦           table.csv
¦
+---PredictProxies
¦   ¦   __init__.py
¦   ¦
¦   +---Prediction
¦   ¦   ¦   PredictionClass.py
¦   ¦   ¦   __init__.py
¦   ¦   ... other  files
```

start_service.bat simply set FLASK_APP=WebService.py and run server.

WebService.py route connection and call method in PredictionClass.py,
but this class use methods contained in CommonClass.py

If i call test_prediction_utils.py, python recognize paths, while if i run flask doesn't:

> from Common_utils.CommonClass import Common
>   ImportError: No module named Common_utils.CommonClass

Below the files:

WebService.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import WebServiceClass as WSC

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/PredictProxies', methods=['GET'])
def PredictProxies():
   print(request.headers)
   if request.method == 'GET':
      wsc = WSC.WebServiceClass()
      response = app.response_class(
         response = wsc.execute(),
         status   = 200,
         mimetype = 'application/json'
      )
      return response
```

WebServiceClass.py
from PredictProxies.Prediction.Prediction_Utils import Prediction

class WebServiceClass(object):
    def **init**(self, file, hedging, ws):
      ...

```
def execute(self):
   ...
   p = Prediction()
   p.run()
```

CommonClass.py

```
class Common(object):
  def __init__(self):
    ...
  def upload(self):
    ...
```

PredictionClass.py

```
from Common_utils.CommonClass import Common
class Prediction(object):
  def __init__(self):
    ...
  def run(self):
    ...
    c = Common()
    ...
```

test_prediction_class.py

```
from PredictProxies.Prediction.PredictionClass import Prediction

def main():
    p = Prediction()
    p.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```